# What scenes are missable and how can I make sure to not miss them?

Tags: final-fantasy-type-0-hd

I'm having a lot of fun with Type-0 HD and I'd really like to earn the Platinum Trophy (without having to start a brand new save file). One of the challenging parts of this is I'm told that in Chapter 8 there are 3 scenes which are **only viewable on your first playthrough** (basically, you can't view them on New Game+ for some reason). From what I've read, viewing these scenes unlock codex entries... and all codex entries are required for another trophy. I'm currently on Chapter 7, but I've heard that in Chapter 8 you have much less time between missions.

Which scenes are these, and how can I make sure to view them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Permanently Missed Content](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_permanently_missable_content)

> If the player completes [Carla](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Carla_Ayatsugi), [Mutsuki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mutsuki_Chiharano), [Quon](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Quon_Yobatz), and [Ryid's](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ryid_Uruk) sidequests to recruit them into Class Zero, they will no longer be present during the final chapter where cutscenes involving them can be viewed.
>
> Because this sidequest completion is carried over into New Game Plus playthroughs, these cutscenes can become permanently missable unless the player does not take on the quests in their first playthrough, for the cutscenes can only be viewed when their respective characters remain unrecruited.
>
> In the HD version, these scenes are available regardless of their respective characters' recruitment status on the first playthrough only. If they are not watched by then, they can be missed permanently.